# How to create a calculation function using enumeration?

Tags: swift, enumeration

I have created an enumeration `CalculationType` and function with properties.
But I think my code should look shorter))

I would like to reduce the number of prints.

```swift
enum CalculationType: Int {
    case addition
    case subtraction
    case multiplication
    case division
}

func calculator(numberOne: Int, numberTwo: Int,_ calculationType: CalculationType) -> Int {
    var result = 0
    switch calculationType {
    case .addition: result = numberOne + numberTwo
    print("Result \(CalculationType.addition): \(numberOne) and \(numberTwo) equels \(result)")
    case .subtraction: result = numberOne - numberTwo
        print("Result \(CalculationType.subtraction): \(numberOne) and \(numberTwo) equels \(result)")
    case .multiplication: result = numberOne * numberTwo
        print("Result \(CalculationType.multiplication): \(numberOne) and \(numberTwo) equels \(result)")
    case .division: result = numberOne / numberTwo
        print("Result \(CalculationType.division): \(numberOne) and \(numberTwo) equels \(result)")
    }
    return result
}

calculator(numberOne: 5, numberTwo: 7, .addition)
calculator(numberOne: 5, numberTwo: 7, .subtraction)
calculator(numberOne: 5, numberTwo: 7, .multiplication)
calculator(numberOne: 5, numberTwo: 7, .division)
```

Comment: Code reviews should be posted at [Code Review](https://codereview.stachexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

I‘d suggest giving `CalculationType` a method to perform the calculation:

```
enum CalculationType {
    case addition
    case subtraction
    case multiplication
    case division
}

extension CalculationType {
    func perform<T: BinaryInteger>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: T) -> T {
        switch self {
        case .addition:       return lhs + rhs
        case .subtraction:    return lhs - rhs
        case .multiplication: return lhs * rhs
        case .division:       return lhs / rhs
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
func calculator(numberOne: Int, numberTwo: Int,_ calculationType: CalculationType) -> Int {
    return calculationType.perform(numberOne, numberTwo)
}
```

---

To handle division by zero, you can either have the caller check to see if the denominator is zero before calling `perform`, or you can have `perform` defined to throw errors:

```
enum CalculationType {
    case addition
    case subtraction
    case multiplication
    case division
}

enum CalculationError: Error {
    case divideByZero
}

extension CalculationType {
    func perform<T: BinaryInteger>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: T) throws -> T {
        switch self {
        case .addition:
            return lhs + rhs

        case .subtraction:
            return lhs - rhs

        case .multiplication:
            return lhs * rhs

        case .division:
            if rhs == 0 { throw CalculationError.divideByZero }
            return lhs / rhs
        }
    }
}
```

And the caller can then check for errors:

```
func calculator(numberOne: Int, numberTwo: Int,_ calculationType: CalculationType) -> Int? {
    do {
        return try calculationType.perform(numberOne, numberTwo)
    } catch CalculationError.divideByZero {
        print("Whoops, divide by zero")
        return nil
    } catch {
        print("Some other error:", error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much)
And how to make a check in the last case on the division by 0?

/////////////////////////////////////////////switch calculationType {
    case .addition: result = a + b; calculationName = "Addition"
    case .subtraction: result = a - b; calculationName = "Subtruction"
    case .multiplication: result = a * b; calculationName = "Multiplication"
    case .division where b != 0: result = a / b; calculationName = "Devision"
    default: print("It is impossible to divide by 0!")

Comment: Change `perform` to be method that `throws` errors and in the `.division` situation, check if `lhs` is zero, and if so, `throw` the error. See example in revised answer. I also corrected confusing inversion of `lhs` and `rhs`.